# Finished Kriat Shema after the deadline

Tags: halacha, zemanim, shema

If I start the Shema before the zman but I finish the 1st 3 paragraphs after the alloted time, what is the halacha?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What else besides the 3 paragraphs is there?

Comment: Do you mean to ask if that is a violation of the deadline? If you fulfilled your obligation correctly?

Comment: There's the issue that we don't know exactly when zmanim are-- most zmanim charts are +/- 2 minutes. If you're starting close enough to the zman that this is an issue, you might want to say that because of doubt, the blessings aren't made, but the shema is still recited, because there's no point where it's prohibited to recite shema.

Comment: the mishna regarding a person in a mikva seems to say you're yotze with the first verse.

Answer (score 4):

There is a machlokes haposkim what portion of Shma is min hatorah (Aruch hashulchan 58:16:
1. First pasuk
2. first parsha
3. First 2 parshios
4. All 3 parshios

Thus, if the sof zman krias shma arrived during Shma, at least you fulfilled the mitzva min hatorah according to so opinions.

There is a fascinating Aruch Hashulchan 110:5 based on Tosfos (who writes that Bilaam only started to curse Bnai Yisroel when Hashem was angry but concluded the curse afterwards) who holds that if one starts during the zman one can finish after the zman. His opinion is probably limited to Tefilah whose time limit is derabanan and does not apply to Shma whose time is min hatorah, but his proof from Bilaam might imply otherwise.

Comment: But does anyone hold the opposite of the _AHS_'s view?

Comment: Not everyone agrees that what we call sof zman krias shma is a biblical time limit.

Comment: @msh210 AH is a huge chiddush not mentioned AFAIK elsewhere which is an indication that his view may not be shared.

Comment: @AA minchas cohen claims it's not min matorah but most poskim disagree. If time limit is not min hatorah then the AH logic would likelier apply.

Comment: Apparently, the Ben Ish Chai holds the interesting view that the majority of the amidah must be recited before the z'man ("כדי שתהיה תפלת המנחה רובה בתוך בין השמשות"). See [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56327).

Comment: added the Aruch Hashulchan its Haveneinu

Answer (score 3):

If the question was regarding fulfilling one's obligation to recite *Shema'* in the morning, Qizur Shulhan 'Arukh - Yalqut Yosef (Orah Hayim 58:2) states (my translation):

> Within *Zeman Qeri'at Shema'* one must read **all three paragraphs** and not just the first.