# Did Jews in Arab countries ever rely on Islamic calls to prayer?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, history, islam, calculation

It just occurred to me that Jews in Arab/Islamic countries would most likely have heard the *adhan* call the populace to prayer five times a day.

Upon looking at an Islamic time-table and doing some research about their various schools and methods of calculation, I found that their scheduled times of prayer roughly equate (*le-havdil*) with our *'aloth ha-shaHar*, *neS ha-Hamah*, *HaSoth*, *minHah qeTanah*, *sheqi'ah*, and *`aravith* (following Rabbenu Tam's *shiTah* of having *Seth ha-kokhavim* be at nautical twilight).

They roughly coincide as follows:

- עלות השחר = *fajr*
- נץ החמה = *shuruuq ash-shams*
- חצות = *duhur*
- מנחה קטנה = *asr*
- שקיעה = *maghreb*
- ערבית\צאת הכוכבים = *ishaa*

So are their any sources for religious Jews in Islamic countries relying the public calls to prayer for their own *tefilloth*?

Comment: The question can likely also be expanded to the Balkans until as far as Wien, where there were sufficient Muslim populaces to necessitate their tefillah b'tzibbur.

Comment: Where I live, the calls to prayer from the next hillside are perfectly audible. People here have been cautioned against depending on these for halachic shkia, eg with accepting Shabbos and davening Mincha.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, there is a history of Jewish communities in Arab countries relying on the Muslim call to prayer for their own praying times. For one such example, here is the Ben Ish Hai, (Hacham Yosef Haim) who lived from 1832-1909 in Baghdad, and who refers to the *maghrab* (an Islamic prayer-time called after sunset) in various places:

> **Ben Ish Hai, Year 1, Vayakhel #4**
>
> וכן המנהג פשוט פה עירנו בגדא"ד יע"א לשער מעמוד השחר עד צאת הכוכבים, כי אצלנו חושבים צאת הכוכבים שליש שעה אחר קריאת המגרב בעיר זו, וכך קבלו לשער בזה מן עט"ר הרה"ג מור זקני רבינו משה חיים זלה"ה
>
> [Regarding the halachic dispute of determining the length of a day] Here in Baghdad, the accepted custom instituted by my grandfather, our teacher R. Moshe Haim z"l, is to calculate the length of the day from daybreak to nightfall, and we calculate nightfall as being twenty minutes after calling *maghrab*

And here's another source, which introduces other locales using this system and provides more sources:

> **Ben Ish Hai, Year 1, Vayakhel #9**
>
> והנה פה עירנו בגדאד יע"א בחנו ונסו הראשונים וראו שבמקום גבוה שבעיר נראית שקיעת החמה שבעה דקים קודם קריאת המגרב, ועל כל העלתי בסה"ק רב פעלים בתשובה בס"ד דפה עירנו אין רשאין להתפלל מנחה אלא עד ששה דקים אחר קריאת המגר"ב, כי עד ששה דקים הוא נקרא בין השמשות ויכולים להתפלל בו מנחה בשעת הדחק לדעת המתירים, וא"כ לא יתחילו להתפלל אלא עד ארבעה דקים אחר קריאת המגר"ב כדי שתהיה תפלת המנחה רובה בתוך בין השמשות. ויש מקומות ששקיעת החמה אצלם עשרה דקים קודם קריאת המגר"ב, וכמ"ש הרה"ג הרח"ף ז"ל על עיר אחת, והם ישערו זמן בין השמשות כפי המצוי בעירם. ושמעתי מנהג עה"ק ירושלים וחברון תוב"ב אם כבר קרא המגר"ב אין מתפללין מנחה לא בחול ולא בשבת, והוא כפי עדות הגאון חיד"א ז"ל ועיין במחב"ר סי' רס"א אות ז' ובסי' תנ"ד אות ב' ועיין עוד בברכ"י ומחב"ר סי' של"א ואדרת אליהו סי' י"ג ותפארת אדם סי' י"א ולב חיים סי' קל"ד יע"ש
>
> And the exact time of sunset in Baghdad has been established in previous generations, by observation from the highest point in the city, as being seven minutes before *maghrab* is called. If one did not pray mincha at the correct time, I conclude in my work Rav Pealim that, here in Baghdad, one may pray until six minutes after *maghrab*, since until then it is still dusk. However, since it is necessary to pray the major portion of the amidah during the permitted time, one should not begin the amidah later than four minutes after *maghrab* is called.
>
> *Maghrab* is not called at the same time in all areas: R. Haim Palagi z"l mentions the case of a city where sunset occurs ten minutes before *maghrab* is called. In that city, the time of dusk must be calculated accordingly.
>
> I have heard that, in the Holy City and in Hevron, if *Maghrab* has already been called, mincha is subsequently not prayed, both during the week and on Shabbat (cf. Birkei Yosef; Mahzik Brachah ch. 331; Aderet Eliyahu ch. 13; Tiferet Adam ch. 11; Lev Haim ch. 134).