# Finished Shema After Zeman

Tags: zemanim, shema

If one started The Shema before the zeman, however the recitation extends into the time after the zeman, where does it say one still finish The Shema? Also, did they meet the obligation if they finished reciting it after the zeman?

Comment: The other question, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37665/finished-kriat-shema-after-the-deadline, didn’t answer my question definitively and explicitly.

Comment: Please clarify what, exactly, wasn't answered. From the other question it appears to be a difference of halachic ruling between different poskim; for a personal p'sak please contact your own rabbi, as we do not give personal p'sakos here.

Comment: I was looking for something more explicit, where from reading one would be able to identify “yes” or “no” from the ruling.

Comment: For "yes or no" ask your rabbi. There are clearly differences of opinion regarding this issue; why do you trust a random Internet person to tell you which opinion *you, personally* should follow?

Comment: It’s not trust, just looking for an answer. But todah.

Comment: answer is "depends who you ask," very clearly in the duplicate question.