# Permissibility of Saying Shema and/or Berakhot After Third Hour

Tags: shema, bircas-krias-shema

Are the Berakhot of the Shema allowed to be said after the third Halakhic hour, or both the Shema and the Berakhot?

Answer (score 2):

[Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 58:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.58.6?lang=bi):

> אע"פ שזמנה נמשך עד סוף השעה הג' אם עברה שעה ג' ולא קראה קורא אותה בברכותיה כל שעה ד' שהוא שליש היום ואין לו שכר כקורא בזמנה ואם עברה שעה ד' ולא קראה קוראה בלא ברכותיה כל היום:‏
>
> Even though its [proper] time continues until the end of the third hour, if the third hour passed and one did not read it, one may read it with its berakhot all the fourth hour, since it's [within] a third of the day. And [if one does this] one doesn't have a reward like one who reads in its [proper] time. And if the fourth hour passed and he didn't read it, one may read it without its berakhot all day.

Note also the opinion of [Biur Halacha ad loc.](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Biur_Halacha.58.6.1?lang=bi) who permits reciting the blessings all the way until midday, if one's failure to recite them by the end of the fourth hour was owing to circumstances beyond one's control (*ones*).

Comment: What if there are circumstances that are not beyond one’s control, can one still say it until the end of the fourth hour or midday?

Comment: @MikayahYisrael According to these sources, clearly only until the end of the fourth hour.

Comment: @DoubleAA what if one is in the middle of saying it, and the end of the third or fourth hour past? Should they still finish it?

Comment: @Mikayah you already asked that question multiple times https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/131206/759